# infine scroll in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
    const InfiScroll = ({items}) => {
        items.map((item) => <Item item=item key={item.key}>
    )}
```

I have a component like shown above and getting the `items` from store and are populate on some event like window scroll etc.

Every time new items are added into `items` the map will be executed over the items array and react takes care of updating only the new items.

Is there any way to not to iterate through all the `items` and just find the new items and add create components for the new ones.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a list with a lot of items (your component's name is InfinityScroll), I'll check this https://github.com/bvaughn/react-virtualized, the performance is much better having virtualized lists instead of having thousands of DOM elements

Comment: I looked at react-virtualized, Making it responsive is another challenge. Im trying to make a responsive grid which I think is not feasible with that

Comment: I see... what about https://github.com/eiriklv/react-masonry-component ?

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but my question is how to skip mapping all the item in the array. Here ill have to map all the objects in order ti give it to the masonry component

Comment: okey, I want to provide some alternatives, unless you have a huge array I don't see the point of avoiding skipping old items and only map the new ones, I think the logic you need to implement to do that is much heavier than processing all the items in the array

Comment: Agreed, Just wanted to know if it is possible, if yes how?

Comment: Maybe you can create an auxiliary array (already processed items) and in the componentWillReceiveProps you can check which items are news and which not and pass that new variable to you render method